# <MOKManager> Replace MOK with the name of the file you want for the key

Tags: vmware

The site:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146460
says:
"Replace MOK with the name of the file you want for the key."
With what should I replace the word "MOK"?
Can I have some examples?

Comment: This question is not related to ubuntu community.

Comment: @learner MOK (machine owner keys) is a Ubuntu utility. See `man mokutil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the web site...

---

1. Generate a key pair using the openssl to sign vmmon and vmnet modules:

$openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout **MOK**.priv -outform DER -out **MOK**.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"

Replace **MOK** with the name of the file you want for the key.

---

They mean replace `MOK.priv` and `MOK.der` with your own filenames... like `riccardo.priv` and `riccardo.der`

Comment: ok, i understand, an name at my choice of the file that will be created after the first command.